# Laravel 5 / Spark - Pass data from form request to controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-spark

Working in Laravel Spark and have a custom API endpoint that checks a user credentials but doesn't log them in, just returns the user data.

I have a form request that checks the email and password for being required and then I use

```
withValidator()
```

to run some more validation on the password.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'email' => 'required|email|exists:users',
        'password' => 'required'
    ];
}

public function withValidator($validator)
{
    $validator->after(function ($validator) {

        $user = User::where('email', $this->email)->first();

        if ( $user && !Hash::check($this->password, $user->password) ) {
            $validator->errors()->add('password', 'Incorrect password');
        } else {
            // Pass the user to the controller
        }

    });
}
```

In my controller I want to be able to return the user, but I dont want to run through the process of checking the hash etc.

I would simply like to be able to do:

```
return $request->user
```

Or similar.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just do this in the controller?

```
$user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();
```

If you put this after the validator, you already know the user is valid, otherwise the validator would fail before it got to that point.